# How to detect where the width of loess 95% CI reach a certain amount?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, loess

I've fitted a loess curve with 95% CI, and now I'd like to be able to determine where the CI get to a certain width.

For example, using the "cars" dataset:

```
plot <- ggplot (cars, aes (x=speed, y=dist)) +
geom_point() +
stat_smooth (method= "loess", se=TRUE) +
xlab("Speed")+
ylab("Distance")+
theme_bw()
plot
```

[image: plot]

I'd like to be able to find out at what values of "Speed" the CIs are equal to 20 units of distance. Looking at the plot, it might be approximately 7 and 24.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggplot_build(plot)` to extract relevant data about the layers built in ggplot2 and other misc information.

In this case, the limits for the confidence intervals are in the `ymin` and `ymax` columns and can be reached with:

```
foo <- ggplot_build(plot)
foo[["data"]][[2]]
```

You can then do a simple mutate to examine the differences between `ymax` and `ymin` and at what "Speed" the CI gap reaches 20 through the `x` column.

```
mutate_info <- foo[["data"]][[2]] %>% dplyr::mutate(ci_gap = ymax-ymin)
```